# Why do I get "Invalid or corrupt jarfile"?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, lwjgl

Before this error I got

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/lwjgl/LWJGLException`

I added `lib/lwjgl.jar` and `lib/lwjgl_util.jar` to `manifest.mf` and that's where I get the error in the title. Any idea how to fix this? I used eclipse to generate the jar and manifest file.

Comment: Are any errors noted when eclipse generates the jar?

Comment: No, I only have some warnings in one of my java files.

Comment: can you extract the jar using any zip tool and check for missing class' class file?

Comment: you added both the jars to manifest.mf ? Are you sure if both the jars are present in the classpath ?

Comment: I made a mistake both jars are located within the jar I'm creating in the path lib/jars/ Still getting the error even with the fixed locations

Comment: if you can post your manifest.mf code, perhabs someone can help you.

Comment: Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: game.Root
Class-Path: lib/jars/lwjgl.jar
lib/jars/lwjgl_util.jar

Comment: Are you sure those jars are in your jar?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [JarSplice](http://ninjacave.com/jarsplice) to bundle the LWJGL library files into one comprehensive executable jar-file. [Here is a tutorial on how.](http://thecodinguniverse.com/lwjgl-exporting-as-jar/)